# xsl:when not working in xsl-fo?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I have sample code like this:

```
<fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select="totalsForMonth/@totalI" />
</fo:block>

<xsl:when test="totalsForMonth/@totalI != '0.0'">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="totalsForMonth/@totalI" />
    </fo:block>
</xsl:when>
```

The output will be:

```
13.0
```

in the exported pdf.

I am expecting to see

```
13.0
13.0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<xsl:when>` must be wrapped in an `<xsl:choose>`. Please also provide us with the input XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up `xsl:when` with `xsl:if`.

`xsl:when` is to select different cases inside an `xsl:choose` block (http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xsltc/xsl_choose_design.html). For a single test, use `xsl:if` (http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xsltc/xsl_if_design.html).

When compared to C or Java: `xsl:choose` is not totally unlike a `switch` statement, except that the *conditions* are in the `when` blocks and not in the `choose` itself. This means you can put any test you want in each, more like a long chained `if .. else if ..` block, where `xsl:otherwise` has the role of a final `else`.

Comment: @KorayTugay: I see you have experience with both Java and C so I added a comparison :)